# Django logout ValueError

Tags: django, django-login

I have a ValueError at logout in Django.
It says: The view django.contrib.auth.logout didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

My code is extremely short:

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/some_page/')
```

I tried with shortcut redirect as well. Probably I misunderstand how this works.

Comment: Please show your url pattern, and the import for `logout`.

Comment: What is the exact stack trace? logout does not return anything .how have you setup your url patterns?

Comment: I had a mistake with urls. Thanks a lot and sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. Works perfectly fine for me.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout , authenticate

def accounts_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    url = reverse("accounts:login")
    return redirect(url, args=(),kwargs={})
```

in your url pattern there should be an URL:

```
url(r'^accounts-login/$', views.accounts_login, name='login'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
return render_to_response('logout.html', {'request': request})
```